# How to change the created/modified/access dates on a folder of files?

Tags: command-line

I took a bunch of vacation photos and didn't realize that the camera date was incorrect. The photos all start at Dec 31, 2012 11:00pm, whereas they should start at June 28, 2022 11:42am. I've looked at the touch and SetFile terminal commands, but just can't seem to find a way to recursively add the proper amount of years, days, minutes, to each file to get them to the correct date. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want to keep the offsets from 12/31/2012, just changing the base, rather than changing them all to the same date and time?  This is not clear to me.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I basically need to add 9 years, 178 days, 12 hours and 42 minutes to all of the files.

Comment: The fine man page for touch(1) describes the -A command-line option.  Whether it supports enough of an offset...

Comment: If you're a programmer this is a fun little exercise. Tcl via the command 'tclsh' can do it. `set t0 [file atime "your file name"]` `set t2 [clock add $t0 9 years 178 days 12 hours 42 minutes]` `file atime "your file name" $t2` This gets the file's atime, bumps it, and sets it. Repeat for `mtime`.

Comment: @aMike I knew there was a reason I needed to learn tcl.  Have an upvote.

Comment: Ha! Thanks!  Yeah, Tcl is an old one, but a good one.

Answer (score 0):

### Operating on files in a directory tree

To operate on all the files in the current directory, if you're running a command that accepts multiple file names, you can use the pattern `*`. To run more complex code, use a for loop.

```
mycommand *
for x in *; do …; done
```

To operate on files in subdirectories as well, in zsh or modern bash (from Brew/MacPorts/Fink/…) but not in `/bin/bash`, use the `**/*` pattern:

```
mycommand **/*
for x in **/*; do …; done
```

You can restrict the file names by changing the last `*` to a pattern, e.g. `*.jpeg` to only act on files with the `.jpeg` extension.

(There are a number of complications but they don't matter here so I won't go into them. All commands in this answer handle spaces in file names correctly.)

As an additional safety, I'll show how to only operate on files that are older than a certain threshold. This way, if you run the command twice, it won't over-shift the second time.  In zsh, this is easy with the [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `my+4` to only match files modified at least 4 years ago. In bash, you can use the `-nt` [conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) to compare the file with a reference file, but it's less convenient.

Alternatively, to operate on files in subdirectories, you can use [`find`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+14.0-RELEASE+and+Ports).

```
find . -name '*.jpeg' -newermt 202001010000 -exec sh -c '…' {} ';'
```

Note that the date filtering assumes that the file's modification times are the dates when the photos were taken, not the dates when you copied them recently. If you only want to change the image metadata, skip the date filtering.

### Image metadata

Since these are images, you'll probably want to modify their [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) metadata. There are several tools that can do this, I'll show how to use [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) (open-source, available from Homebrew and other package sources).

Exiftool has a convenient command to [shift times by a certain amount](https://exiftool.org/#shift). (You aren't the first to run into this problem.) You do need to be a little careful because the original date range includes a leap day, so you can't just add years/months/days independently. All dates need to shift by 179 days (to June 28, 2013) plus 9×365+2 (from 2013 to 2022, including two leap days), i.e. 3466 days total. You can also tell exiftool to reset the file's modification time to the Exif metadata (by default, the file's modification time would be the current time, since you've just modified the file).

```
exiftool -if '$CreateDate lt "2020:01:01"' -AllDates+='3466 12:42' -'FileModifyDate<DateTimeOriginal' **/*.jpg
```

### File modification times

You can use the [`date`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=date&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+14.0-RELEASE+and+Ports) command to print either a particular time or the modification time of a file in various formats. (Both the built-in `/bin/date` and the GNU version have these capabilities, but with slightly different syntax; here I'll use the options for `/bin/date`.) So the plan is, for each file:

1. Use `date -r FILENAME +%s` to get the file's modification time as a number of seconds since a fixed origin.
2. Use shell arithmetic to add the desired number of seconds to the time from step 1.
3. Use `date` to print the time calculated at step 2 in a format that `touch` understands.
4. Use `touch` to set the file's modification time.

We can also use `date` and arithmetic to calculate the number of seconds to add to the time.

```
echo $(($(date -j -f %Y%m%dT%H%M 20220628T1142 +%s) - $(date -j -f %Y%m%dT%H%M 20121231T2300 +%s)))
```

Let's put this all together using `find`:

```
delta=$(($(date -j -f %Y%m%dT%H%M 20220628T1142 +%s) - $(date -j -f %Y%m%dT%H%M 20121231T2300 +%s)))
find . -type f ! -newermt 202001010000 -exec sh -c 't=$(date -r "$1" +%s); touch -t $(date -r $((t + $0)) +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S) "$1"' $delta {} ';'
```

And here's a zsh solution:

```
delta=$(($(date -j -f %Y%m%dT%H%M 20220628T1142 +%s) - $(date -j -f %Y%m%dT%H%M 20121231T2300 +%s)))
for x in **/*.jpeg(.my+4); do
  t=$(date -r "$x" +%s)
  touch -t $(date -r $((t + delta)) +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S) $x
done
```

Answer (score -1):

The app [A Better Finder Attributes](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11143/a-better-finder-attributes), although a bit pricy for some at US$19.95, is an amazing tool for, well, changing file & folder attributes.

Here are screenshots of the date manipulation options:

[image]

Additional options under the **Action:** drop-down:

[image]

*Note: I'm a satisfied paying user of the apps A Better Finder Attributes and A Better Finder Renamer, and have no financial or other ties to the developer.*

Comment: This is the "correct" answer in terms of which software to use, but it would be much clearer if a) the screenshots were the other way round and b) they showed using "Adjust creation and modification dates" (not setting creation date). Better to link to developer  https://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderAttributes/index.html

Comment: I will take a look at the app. But I have to believe that this can be accomplished in Terminal as most of these finder and disk editing apps are merely GUIs for Terminal commands.

Comment: Sure it can be done with a script, but rather than taking days/weeks to get assistance, you could have used ABFA and fixed all the dates in 5 minutes.